# How to insert meta tag to the head using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add a meta tag dynamically, I tried [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VnXYB/), from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807761/angular-modify-meta-tag#answer-20810045).

page:

```
<html ng-app="meumobiApp" ng-controller="SiteCtrl">
    <head>
        <smart-banner></smart-banner>
    </head>
    <body></body>
<html>
```

and directive:

```
module.directive("smartBanner",function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content=""></meta>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope) {}   
   }
});
```

But the tag is being inserted in the body tag instead of the head.

It's possible to insert tags to the head or I must try something else?

Comment: Why would you want to add `meta`  tags with JavaScript? Don't think whatever reads that will pick it up.

Comment: @putvande because javascript is the coolest server-side scripting language ever. Ever heard of `node.js`?

Comment: @pqnet yep. But OP is using AngularJS, not nodejs.

Comment: @putvande https://www.google.com/search?q=angularjs+server+side+rendering i guess

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I searched and found nothing stating that create meta tags with javascript doesn't work or work, anyone have any article, doc, link, fiddle or anything that talk about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your directive link function you should do like this

```
module.directive("smartBanner",function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content=""></meta>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope) {
         var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');
         metaTag.name = "apple-itunes-app";
         metaTag.content = "";
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
        }   
   }
});
```

but also you can do this without directive, but nevertheless directive also good idea